# Foreach sem repetir o nome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, foreach

Tenho um Foreach na View, e ela contém Descrcao, qtd e dta,como faço para fazer um foreach sem repetir a descrição?
Ex: tenho um produto X cujo foram retirados 10 unidades dia 01/10/2016, 3 unidades dia 04/10/2016, 8 unidades dia 15/10/2016, como faço para exibir a descrição uma única vez e as datas e as quantidades normalmente?

```
<style type="text/css">
        .leftDivItem, .rightDivItem {
         border: none;
         float: left;
         width: 29%; /*Aumentar ou diminuir a porcentagem para adicionar ou tirar*/
         overflow: hidden;
         margin-right: 2%;
         margin-left: 2%;
         float: left;
         width: 19%;
         overflow: hidden;
         margin-right: 3%;
         margin-left: 3%;*/
  }
  </style>

   int i = 0;
   foreach (var item in Model)
       {
           if (i % 2 == 0)
           {
               <div class="leftDivItem">
                   <span class="listCol2">
                       <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Produto.Descricao)</i><br />
                       <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Produto.Qtd)</i><br />
                       <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Produto.dta)</i>
                       <br />
                       <br />
                   </span>
               </div>
          }
          else
          {
              <div class="rightDivItem" id="textShadow">
                  <span class="listCol2">
                      <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Produto.Descricao)</i><br />
                      <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Produto.Qtd)</i><br />
                      <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Produto.dta)</i>
                      <br />
                      <br />
                   </span>
              </div>
           }
           i++;
       }
```

no código que estou mostrando, o

`<i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Produto.Descricao)</i><br />`

e sei que ele vai se repetir várias vezes pq ele está ali, mas queria saber como posiciono ele para não repetir, e sim apareça uma única vez! Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver o problema é fazendo um agrupamento pela descrição. Eu vou usar o elemento `table` porque o exemplo fica mais facil, podera ter que fazer ajustes para o seu layout:

```
<table>
@foreach(var grupo in Model.GroupBy(i => i.Produto.Descricao)){
    <tr>
        <td rowSpan="@grupo.Count()"> grupo.Key </td> 
    <tr>
    @foreach(var item in grupo){
       <tr> 
           <td>item.Produto.Descricao</td>
           <td>item.Produto.Qtd</td>
           //...
        <tr>
    }
}
</table>
```

Para ordenar pela quantidade basta meter um `OrderBy` no `grupo`.

```
grupo.OrderByDescending(i => i.Produto.Qtd)
```

Comment: Deu certo, mas queria saber como faço para ordenar pela quantidade?

Comment: No caso seria assim, ele vem ordenado pela descrição, e cada descrição tem varias quantidades e datas, queria além de ordenar pela descrição, ordenar também pela quantidade. Ex: 

Produto X - 10 unidades - 01/10/2016
                   3 unidades - 04/10/2016
                   8 unidades - 15/10/2016

Comment: Produto Y - 2 unidades - 01/10/2016
                   30 unidades - 04/10/2016
                   8 unidades - 15/10/2016

fosse ordenado pela quantidade... ficando assim:
Produto X - 10 unidades - 01/10/2016
                   8 unidades - 15/10/2016
                   3 unidades - 04/10/2016

Produto Y - 30 unidades - 04/10/2016
                   8 unidades - 15/10/2016
                   2 unidades - 01/10/2016

Comment: @FabioSouza Editei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado. salvou minha pele rs

Comment: @FabioSouza Se ajudei, vote e aceite a resposta.

Comment: Desculpas, é que eu sou novo aqui, não entendo muito sobre como funciona o site... eu aceitei a resposta, mas como faço pra votar?

Comment: @FabioSouza Tem duas setas bem perto de aceitar, uma para baixo (voto contra) e outra para cima (voto positivo). [Faca o tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: quando clico para votar ele aparece esta mensagem

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: @FabioSouza Abrigado pelo aviso Fábio. Vou pedir a comunidade para traduzir a mensagem. "Obrigado pelo feedback! Os votos dos utilizadores com menos de 15 reputacao sao guardadados, mas nao mudam a contagem de votos do *post*". Ou seja, nao se preocupe.